# Update column value from hierarchical/nested Dataset

Tags: dataset

Let's say I have the following nested dataset:

```
SeedRandom[14];
data=Transpose@Dataset@AssociationThread[{"a","b"},RandomInteger[{0,20},{2,50}]];
data=data[All,<|#,"combine"-><|"c"->Slot@"a"*2,"d"->Slot@"a"-Slot@"b"|>|>&]
```

[image]

I want to selectively apply a function, say `f`, onto the nested column `c` and keep the structure of the original dataset. Currently, I used the following to do it.

```
Dataset[Transpose[  (Transpose@data)[<|#, "combine" -> Normal@data[All, "combine", {"c" -> f}]|> &]  ] ,  MaxItems -> 5]
```

[image]

I found in the `Dataset` doc that `dataset[All,{n->f}]` can `selectively map f onto the n^th column`, which worked for col `b`.

```
Dataset[data[All, {"b" -> f}], MaxItems -> 5]
```

However, when I applied the following. Only the innermost subdataset was updated/returned.

```
Dataset[data[All, "combine", {"c" -> f}], MaxItems -> 5]
```

[image]

Is it possible to correct this? I also wonder is there any other way to return what I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: `MapAt[f, data, {All, 3, 1}]` ?

Comment: @BenIzd Thanks! I modified a little `MapAt[f, data, {All, "combine", "c"}]` to better suit my data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can express the desired operation by using nested subquery operators:

```
data[All, {"combine" -> {"c" -> f}}]
```

[image: dataset]

Comment: This is the answer I expected when posted the question. I just don't know how to nest it. I tried something like `{"combine"/"c"->f}` or `{#combine,#c}->f` but no luck:). Following this structure, I guess I can apply it to the even deeper layer by `{"key1"->{"key2"->{"key3"->f}}}`? Thanks again!