# Updating multiple columns based on a nested value in an association, create a nested function?

Tags: list-manipulation, dataset, nested-function

I have a dataset that looks like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/zafxvr5bispfjyttl6229/a1-data.json?rlkey=zmftvdok9blff8i1i15o87k57&dl=0) and I sorted them by ts since that corresponds to the values of when the data was taken. After reading the primer on associations and keys, and this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/246364/update-column-value-from-hierarchical-nested-dataset), I wanted to operate within the data. So for example, I would like to divide the values of "lamb" by "integration_time" from the same ts association and do the same for "filter" on "spectrum", and then ideally plot them all together in the same plot.

I tried to break it down and see if I can even access the nested "parameters" with:

```
MapAt[f, a1, {All, "parameters", "A"}]

a1[All, {"parameters" -> {"A" -> f}}]
```

But it returned error,"Part[All, "parameters", "filter"} of Association [<<228>>] does not exist."

I tried again with this code from a related question:

```
filter = Select[#["parameters", "A"] &];
Query[A]@a1
```

I tried to specify a range, but same problem. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong here exactly? Also, when I try to KeyDrop "time" for example, it wouldn't even work. I would also appreciate any more efficient approaches instead of (sorting data>perform operation> update dataset>plot).

Sample data, for First[a1]:

```
{<|"time" -> "202301222_202041", 
  "parameters" -> <|"A" -> 40., 
    "B" -> 8., 
    "C" -> 0|>|>, <|"time" -> "202301222_202041", 
  "X" -> {121.076, 121.085, 121.094, 121.103, 121.112, 121.121, 121.13, 121.139, 121.148, 121.157, 121.167, 121.176, 121.185, 121.194, 121.203, 121.212, 121.221, 121.23, 121.239, 121.248, 121.257, 121.266, 121.275, 121.284, 121.293, 121.302, 121.311, 121.32, 121.329, 121.338, 121.347, 121.356, 121.365, 121.374, 121.383, 121.392, 121.401, 121.41, 121.419, 121.428, 121.437, 121.446, 121.455, 121.464, 121.473, 121.482, 121.491, 121.499, 121.508, 121.517, 121.526, 121.535, 121.544, 121.553, 121.562}, 
  "Y" -> {121.076, 121.085, 121.094, 121.103, 121.112, 121.121, 121.13, 121.139, 121.148, 121.157, 121.167, 121.176, 121.185, 121.194, 121.203, 121.212, 121.221, 121.23, 121.239, 121.248, 121.257, 121.266, 121.275, 121.284, 121.293, 121.302, 121.311, 121.32, 121.329, 121.338, 121.347, 121.356, 121.365, 121.374, 121.383, 121.392, 121.401, 121.41, 121.419, 121.428, 121.437, 121.446, 121.455, 121.464, 121.473, 121.482, 121.491, 121.499, 121.508, 121.517, 121.526, 121.535, 121.544, 121.553, 121.562}|>}
```

Comment: I see that you included an attachment, but could you make your question self-contained by including at least a few representative entries from your data?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, updated.

Comment: @atomic-muclei The "sample data" is not valid WL.

Comment: @Alan Thank you, just updated.

Comment: @atomic-muclei So calling your example object `lst`, do you want something like `<|"new" -> #"lamb"/#"spectrum"|> & /@ Join @@@ GatherBy[lst, #"ts" &]`?

Comment: @Alan Yes exactly! But I would like to divide lamb by filter which is under parameters, this is where I am stuck. If I understand the error messages correctly), I have two associations (ts1, ts2) so I can't part them. If I inquire about my key values for datset, it returns only ts.

Comment: @atomic-muclei That's no problem in principle, but what do you want to happen when (as in your example) `nd_filter` is zero?

Comment: @Alan Oh sorry, so it would be dividing it by (nd_filter + 1)

Comment: @atomic-muclei In that case, see the proposed answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let `lst` be the example list in the question. The

```
unify = Join @@@ GatherBy[lst, #"time" &]
result = <|"new" -> #"X"/(1 + #"parameters"["A"])|> & /@ unify
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I just tried it and it works perfectly. May I ask how would I identify them later when I plot them all together? So for example will I be able to remove a certain datapoint (a ts association)?

Comment: @atomic-muclei You can keep `ts` as well by changing the function to `<|"ts" -> #"ts", "new" -> #"lamb"/(1 + #"parameters"["nd_filter"])|> &`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Hi @Alan, sorry but I just changed the variable names so the question can be clearer. `nd_filter -> A, ts -> time, lamb -> X`.

Answer (score 4):

```
new = 
  With[{as = <|lst|>}, 
    {<|"new" -> as["X"]/(1 + as["parameters", "A"])|>}];

new == result

(* True *)
```